# Java 8: How to sort and collect two nested Maps with ArrayList inside?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a nested Map of the following type `LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Commit>>>`. The key of the first map stores some usernames, the key of the second map is a repository names of the users and inside the ArrayList I have an object with some attributes like hash, message, additions, etc.

After I sort alphabetically the whole collection by the key of the first map and the key of the second one how could I collect (save) my nested map in the new collection of the same type (the object remains unchanged)?

I need to do this using lambda and Stream API. Here is the way I am trying to do that:

```java
LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Commit>>> sorted = gitUsers.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted((u1, u2) -> u1.getKey().compareTo(u2.getKey()))
            .map(u -> u.getValue()
                    .entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .sorted((r1, r2) -> collator.compare(r1.getKey(), r2.getKey())))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue,(a, b) -> a, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

I'm definitely doing something wrong because I keep getting the following message "Non-static method cannot be referenced from a static context" and can't collect the map. I guess I can't assemble my map successfully because of the `.map()` function and the second stream I've used.

I know you would suggest me to use a TreeMap or to sort the collection and print it right away using `.foreach()` method in my lambda (what I already did by the way), but I need to do it exactly that way like I've described above.

For the purposes of my Programming Fundamentals course this problem should be resolved that way. Hope for your help!

P.S. I was looking for the solution for a long period of time and did research everywhere including Stack Overflow forums and didn't find anything corresponding to the requested way of resolving the problem.

Comment: What type does gitUsers.entrySet() return?

Comment: gitUsers is a Map of the following type `LinkedHashMap<String, LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<Commit>>> gitUsers = new LinkedHashMap<>();` as I mentioned in the beginning of my post. It is the initial Map which I sorted by the key of the first Map and the key of the second nested Map and now I want to collect it - both maps with ArrayList inside collect to Map of the same type.

Comment: Please see my answer. I also do recommend you rename your post to: *how to do nested map sorting* or smth since it is more generic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code not compiled even I remove sorting by unknown `collator` comparator.

Valid code is:

```
Map<String, Map<String, List<Commit>>> collect = h.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                e -> e.getValue()
                        .entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey())
                        .collect(
                                Collectors.toMap(
                                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                                        (a, b) -> a,
                                        LinkedHashMap::new
                                )
                        ),
                (a, b) -> a,
                LinkedHashMap::new
                )
        );
```

Note that you can replace with your comparator instead of `Map.Entry.comparingByKey()`.

Comment: I used `Collator collator = Collator.getInstance();` so java could compare strings like c# do that and print lowercase letters first and then capital letters. It's needed for our Open Judge System and tests for this problem, I forgot to change it in my example, sorry.
Thank you very much for your answer and corrected code! I will try it now and will write you back.

Comment: I made a mistake. Corrected my answer. Now it is OK

Comment: "I also do recommend you rename your post to: how to do nested map sorting or smth since it is more generic" but the problem for me was to collect it correctly as well. I will try to rename my post and specify the problem more correctly.

Comment: Yes, the more generic topic is the more useful for the community :)

Comment: Thank you very much, your code works perfectly! :) I was struggling with this problem for too long, I had to ask here earlier. Thank you again.

Comment: How could I use my custom `collator` comparator in the second sort function? This `.sorted((a, b) -> collator.compare(a.getKey, b.getKey))` doesn't work.

Comment: I managed it `.sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(collator))`. Everything is ok. :)

Answer (score 0):

2 cents, I suggest you to try out `EntryStream` provided [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex) for Map Stream operations. Here is solution by my [Fork of StreamEx](https://github.com/landawn/streamex).

```
StreamEx.of(gitUsers).sortedBy(Entry::getKey)
        .toMap(Entry::getKey, 
               e -> EntryStream.of(e.getValue()).sortedBy(Entry::getKey).toMap(LinkedHashMap::new), 
               () -> new LinkedHashMap<>());
```

To me, the code is straightforward and shorter, and easier to understand. By the way, I think interface is always preferred. To me `Map<String, Map<String, List<Commit>>>` is better.

Comment: Thank you for your solution! If I finally become a developer I will keep it in mind. :) I needed a solution that uses just plain java because of our Judge System, it can test and compile the program only using standard libraries.